# Collapsible Sidebar Elements in EmberJS

Tags: css, ember.js

I have a list I want to function as a sidebar, which consists of music genres, and sub-genres.

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |genre|}}
    <li>
      {{#link-to "listen.genre" genre}}
        {{genre.title}}
      {{/link-to}}
      <ul>
        {{#each genre.subgenre as |subgenre|}}
          {{#link-to "listen.genre.subgenre" genre subgenre}}<li>{{subgenre.title}}</li>{{/link-to}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

My difficulty is figuring out how to have only the selected genre display its sub-genres. I have a bit of css which works if I can somehow add the 'active' class to the appropriate genre.

```
li ul {
  display: none;
}

li.active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ember-cli-active-link-wrapper](https://github.com/alexspeller/ember-cli-active-link-wrapper) for this. I think there is an RFC to implement something like this in ember itself.